# Problems with worksheet change methods; unable to change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the following code in my worksheet to work. At the moment it does nothing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "j4" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value = 0 Then
        Range("j5").Value = 1
    Else
        Range("j5").Value = 2
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

The code's placed in the worksheet, and the macro security is set to "Enable all macros".

I'm using the 64-bit version of excel 2010.

Thank you for any help you can offer.
James

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of J5 when J4 is changed?

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for this? It's about 20 times easier to write a formula in cell J5 instead.

Comment: Indeed, you're right but it was a test of the technique so I can apply it to more complicated examples that can only be done like this. I hate coming here without a concrete example though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your first `If` statement. The following code should work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J4")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If (Target = 0) Then
            Range("J5") = 1
        Else
            Range("J5") = 2
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, worked briliantly. How would you recommend extending this for a select?

Comment: ah, this doesn't work, if the control cell (i.e. J4) is a select pull-down. Any suggestions?

Comment: @James. Simplest non-VBA solution would be to have cell J5 formula as `=IF(J4 = 0, 1, 2)`. I only have Excel 2003 so not sure what 'select pull-down' is? It works on my desktop if you use `Data > Validation` and populate the drop down menu by selecting `List` and setting `Source` accordingly.

Comment: This was only a simple example, think I might have to post the whole thing up, but that would be best done in another question. Your help's been invaluable though.